# Cómo usar una URL enviada desde js, en un datagrid php

Tags: javascript, php, json, url, datagrid

Tengo una función js que devuelve la URL de una API que necesito usar en un datagrid. Esta api mostrará los alumnos asignados a un profesor, y esta cuadrícula de datos tiene que cambiar según el usuario (profesor que inició la sesión), y esta función es la que devuelve la api que me da el json para cada profesor

```
function newdatagrid(){
  SESION_USUARIO = obtenerUsuarioSesion();
  var usuario = SESION_USUARIO;
  console.log('El usuario es: ', usuario);
  var url = url1 + '/apis/alumnosasignados/' + usuario;
  console.log( url);
  return url;
}
```

lo que no sé es cómo enviar este url desde mi archivo js a mi archivo php, que es donde está la cuadrícula de datos. (que ahora tiene una URL estática para realizar pruebas).

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" id="dgper3" nowrap="false" data-options="
       iconCls: 'icon-edit',
       singleSelect: true,
       required:true,
       method: 'get',
       url: http://localhost/apis/alumnosasignados/24'
    ">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th
                data-options="
                field:'id',
                onDblClick:openWinPermisoLaboralter,
                align:'center'"
                width="5%">Id</th>
            <th
                data-options="
                field:'nombre_completo',
                onDblClick:openWinPermisoLaboralter,
                align:'center'"
                width="30%">Nombre completo</th>
            <th
                data-options="
                field:'estado',
                onDblClick:openWinPermisoLaboralter,
                align:'center'"
                width="8%">Estado</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

el json regresa:

```
[
    {
        "id": 66,
        "nombre_completo": "Ingrid López",
        "estado": "INSCRITO"
    },
    {
        "id": 67,
        "nombre_completo": "Elmer Martinez",
        "estado": "INSCRITO"
    }]
```

Intenté enviar la URL de esta manera, pero la adjunta a otra URL que no es funcional.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function javascript_to_php() {
    var url = newdatagrid();
    console.log( url);
    window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?name=" + url;
}
</script>
 
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">' , 'javascript_to_php();' , '</script>';
// comprobar si tenemos los parametros w1 y w2 en la URL
if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    // asignar w1 y w2 a dos variables
    $phpVar1 = $_GET["name"];
    // mostrar $phpVar1 y $phpVar2
    echo "<p>Parameters: " . $phpVar1 . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>No parameters</p>";
}
?>
```

al final necesito una forma de consumir las apis editadas en el datagrid.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui la solucion, en mi codigo php solo deje una tabla pero sin funcion

```
<table id="dgper3"></table>
```

y en el encabesado de este mismo php hago que la siguiente funcion se carge en automatico.

```
<?php
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">' , 'newdatagrid();' , '</script>';
?>
```

Y en javascript programe la siguiente funcion

```
function newdatagrid(){
    SESION_USUARIO = obtenerUsuarioSesion();
    var usuario = SESION_USUARIO;
    console.log('El usuario es: ', usuario);


    var ourl = 'http://localhost/apis/alumnosasignados/' + usuario;

    console.log( ourl);
  
        $('#dgper3').datagrid({
          singleSelect: true,
          required:true,
          method: 'get',
          url:ourl,
          columns:[[
              {field:'id',title:'ID',width:'5%',align:'center'},
              {field:'nombre_completo',title:'Fecha',width:'44%',align:'center'},
              {field:'estado',title:'Descripcion',width:'15%',align:'center'},
          ]]
      });
        return ourl;
  }
```

lo cual hace que el datagrid cambie segun el usuario de la sesión.